# How to search for records with timestamp between two given time in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to search through timestamp data in a database and select only data with timestamps between 8AM and 6PM?

Example timestamp format is `2021-06-14 14:01:26.839629`, I want to do a search and only return results where time is after 8AM and before 6PM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (as per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
```

This will return the hour from the timestamp and you can also filter accordingly.

Comment: Thanks below is working for me now SELECT
  "timestamp" AS "time",
  occupancy
FROM data
where  
 extract(hour from timestamp) > 8 
 AND extract(hour from timestamp) < 18;
;

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select *
from MyTable
where CAST(Created as time) >= '08:00' 
   or CAST(Created as time) < '18:00'
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
where col::time >= '06:00:00' and col::time < '18:00:00'
```